# Getting ERROR When I install 'OpenAI baselines' in Windows with 'pip install -e'

Tags: pip, installation, openai-gym

I'm new to python, and I want to install OpenAI baselines in Windows. And I follow the official installation guidance in https://github.com/openai/baselines. But when I run the code pip install -e ., I get the following wrong:

I think maybe I need to modify the setup.py, but I don't know how to solve.

```
assert LooseVersion(re.sub(r'-?rc\d+$', '', tf_pkg.version)) >= LooseVersion('1.4.0')
    AssertionError

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in D:\myGitHub\baselines\
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/1b092434fc51efcb25d6650e287f07634ada1e08/setup.py#L61:

> TensorFlow needed, of version above 1.4

So run `pip install -U tensorflow` or `pip install -U tensorflow-gpu` if you have [a supported GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).